# IBM Worklight Adapter parsing JSON

Tags: json, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
      {
         "name": "pradeep",
         "password": 123,
         "timestamp": "2014-04-08T12:58:45.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "dileep",
         "password": 1234,
         "timestamp": "2014-04-08T13:00:52.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

This invocation result i have got by using  Sql adapter so how to parse this invocation result and how can i display name,password,timestamp from this JSON object.Do i need to use HTTP Adapter.

Comment: What is your actual problem? A WL Adapter is just plain javascript, nothing difficult to do there...

Comment: I want to display the resultSetvalues.so how can i do.And where should i write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the length of results you should use result.invocationResult.resultSet.length which will give you the total number of results, where items is the response coming from the adapter and invocationResult contains the results and other paramaters, from which you will have to access the results for accessing only the particular output.To get value call

result.invocationResult.resultSet.name[position]

Like that call all the fields password,timestamp with position
in for loop

```
function handleSuccess(result) {



    var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
    var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
    if (true == isSuccessful) {
        var result = invocationResult.resultSet;

        for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            alert(result.name[i]);
                            alert(result.password[i]);
                            alert(result.timestamp[i]);
        }

    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
```

Comment: Okay this code where i need to write it.Inside my procedure.

Comment: You have to write above code to inside your procedure successcallback function

Comment: Im  new to IBM worklight so plz give me good link so that i can study worklight thoroughly.

Comment: but whatever we write in procedure it will get converted to invocation result

Comment: We get invocationresult only as a result of invokeprocedure method in Worklightadapter.For our need, we have to parse the that result.